# Importing types alongside main import with import/require

Tags: typescript, types, airtable

I'm writing a definition file for airtable, and unfortunately, they are exporting only one class like this:

```
...

module.exports = Airtable;
```

So, my `airtable.d.ts` file looks like this:

```
declare module "airtable" {
    export type MyType = { ... };

    export class Airtable {
        ...
    }

    export = Airtable;
}
```

When I'm importing the `Airtable` class it works great:

```
import Airtable = require("airtable");
...
new Airtable(...)
```

But I can't find a way to import `MyType` as well:

```
let a: Airtable.MyType;
```

Results in this error:

> 'Airtable' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace
>   here

And:

```
import { MyType } from "airtable";
```

Results in these errors:

> Module "airtable" has no exported member 'MyType'
>   Module "airtable" resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct

Any idea how I can import other exported types while keep using `export =` and `import/require`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer really depends on how you're going to use the types. If you're using them in your own project, you need a file (called `<whatever>.d.ts`) that declares a module called `"airtable"`. In that, you'll need to export something. Since you're exporting a class, you have to use the `export = X` syntax rather than `export X` because you're changing the entire export object rather than adding a property. on the export object (more on that in a sec). As for the types, outside the module in your `.d.ts` file, you can also `decalre` a type that will become globally available. If that rubs you the wrong way (or you're worried about conflicts), you can put your type into a module as well. Since it's a typescript-only thing, it doesn't have to be backed by any js code. You can then import/export it like normal:

```
// my.d.ts

declare module 'airtable' {
  class Airtable {
    constructor(opts?: MyType)
  }
  export = Airtable
}

declare type MyType = string | number

declare module 'AirtableTypes' {
  export type MyString = string
  export type MyNumber = number
}
```

and usage

```
// index.ts
import Airtable from 'airtable'
import AirtableTypes from 'AirtableTypes'

const a = new Airtable('a')

const n: MyType = 3

const s: AirtableTypes.MyString = '3'
```

If you want to add types to `DefinitelyTyped` (which I'm sure they would appreciate!) you can follow the guide [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) to author the declaration file.

It'll point you at

You (correctly) noted that Airtable exports a single class, which doesn't play super nicely with TS. There's some discussion [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13627). Either way, the above guide will point you at [`module-class.d.ts`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-class-d-ts.html), which lets you declare an exported class and accompanying types. You couldn't use this above, as the format is only available when definition files live in the module root or `@types/<module>`.

```
/*~ This declaration specifies that the class constructor function
 *~ is the exported object from the file
 */
export = Airtable

/*~ Write your module's methods and properties in this class */
declare class Airtable {
  constructor(opts?: Airtable.AirtableMethodOptions)
}

/*~ If you want to expose types from your module as well, you can
 *~ place them in this block.
 */
declare namespace Airtable {
  export interface AirtableMethodOptions {
    endpointUrl: string
  }
}
```

Comment: I finally got back to dealing with this, and I went with the `AirtableTypes` module solution. It's a bit sketchy but it's quick and it works. Thanks.